# Trying to use Switch statement in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

```
=Switch(Fields!CompnyID.Value=5, "company 1" "dsSalesManagement", Fields!CompnyID.Value=6, "company 2" "dsSalesManagement" )
```

Trying to use switch statement to display two different results in my report.
Was maybe looking for syntax correction or is there a way to use an else if statement? Problem is I want this expression to be dependent on value from another expression. Is that possible in ssrs?
 [image: ErrorList]

Comment: You're got two strings in each result (`"company 1" "dsSalesManagement"`) - what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: SSRS asks me to specify a dataset aggregate. I dont know how to get around it and its included in my other expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have more than one datasource in your report so you have to specify the correct scope of your aggregate function.

For example:

```
=Switch(
    First(Fields!CompnyID.Value, "dsSalesManagement") = 5, "company 1",
    First(Fields!CompnyID.Value, "dsSalesManagement") = 6, "company 2" 
)
```

Comment: Man, You are so money and you dont even know it!

Comment: @LeonardoTrimarchi ho dovuto guardare su http://www.urbandictionary.com il significato! ;)

Comment: Stavo cercando di dire che questa era una soluzione brillante che veramente mi ha lasciato senza fiato . Grazie mille fratello

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an IIF (immediate if) statement.  The MSDN page is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is here:

```
                                 V-----------------------------V
=Switch(Fields!CompnyID.Value=5, "company 1" "dsSalesManagement",
```

the expression must only return *one* value, so something like:

```
=Switch(Fields!CompnyID.Value=5, "company 1" , ...)
```

Would be *syntactically* correct, but I'm not clear how `"dsSalesManagement"` is involved, so the actual result expression may be different.

> SSRS asks me to specify a dataset aggregate.

Then you may want a calculated field on the dataset that uses `Switch` to return the right field value, then use *that* field in the aggregate.